# Good GTD/todo/tasks app

Tags: macos, mac, applications, software-recommendation, reminders

I am looking for a free task management application that has the following:
- Reminders for tasks that can be snoozed (like native reminders app)
- Grouping tasks/Adding subtasks
- UI showing tasks per day/week
- Prioritize task

I tried Wunderlist and Todoist. Wunderlist has a very nice interface but can not snooze tasks. Todoist also is missing time setting per task.
Anydo seems not working properly. Sometimes I get a popup others not.
What can you recommend?

**Update:**
I have checked the apps in the linked post. They are not meeting my requirement. None offers snooze

Comment: If you explicitly don't want any computer involvement, - please add that to your requirements. The answers on the linked question all serve well for iOS only tools, however.

Comment: @bmike:I am not sure what you mean by "any computer involvement". I am interested in laptop app mainly. I have already tried the apps mentioned in the linked post already and are not sufficient

Comment: I suspect that you will have trouble finding an app that meets all of your requirements while not paying the developer for it (aside from ads). Most freemium apps have more limited features.

Comment: @bassplayer7:But I don’t have such big requirements. If the native reminder app, had the possibility to group subtasks it would be perfect. What I need from the free once is just the possibility to snooze. Wunderlist, Todoist don’t do that. Anydo neither (but it doesn’t work anyway at least in my laptop)

Comment: You can have multiple lists in the native reminders app as well.

Answer (score 0):

I like [Clear](http://realmacsoftware.com/clear/).

It has reminders that can be snoozed. The snooze time is not optional (unlike the default Reminders app). When you snooze, it simply snoozes for 15 minutes.

You can create any number of categories under which to put tasks.

You can very easily prioritize tasks.

It doesn't really have a "today" or "this week" view *except* as a widget in Notification Center.

The UI is unbelievably easy and efficient to use.

Comment: Clear is not free though

Comment: That is correct. It is a high quality app and as such it makes sense for the developer to make income from it. The cost is very reasonable.